# Running strace in the background

Tags: linux, strace

I want to rut strace in the background. For example, 
I'm running

```
strace -esetsid setsid sleep 123
```

but I want to continue running other things until setsid returns. Obviously, simply appending & to

```
sleep 123
```

is interpreted as part of the command to trace. 
So, how do I run this in the background?

I use strace just to get the pid of the new session started by setsid. If there's a better way to do this than strace, I'd like to know too :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setsid -w sleep 123 &
ppid=$! # get the pid of the setsid command that we just launched
pid=`ps --ppid $ppid --no-headers | awk '{ print $1 }'`
```

(with `-w`, setsid waits for the process to exit - and stays on as its parent; `ps --ppid N` is used to select the processes whose parent is the setsid process - there should be only one of those - or none, if the child process exits before the shell gets to execute `ps`. Be sure to check for this - $pid will be empty, then).

Comment: at least on my system, setsid -w sleep 123 & returns "execvp: No such file or directory" and does not work

Comment: check `man setsid` for the options supported by your version of `setsid`. It might not support '-w', but may have a different option that will be helpful.

Comment: Also, have you checked if your `setsid` waits for the child process to exit? (try simply with `setsid sleep 30`). If it does, then just drop the `-w` option from the code I posted, it will work.

Comment: I've checked man setsid. it supports no options whatsoever. I've also tried setsid sleep 30 to see if setsid waits, and it does not. it terminates immediately. Hence my difficulty, because working with $! was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with running something in the background and then attaching to it is that you may already loose some of the information. I would therefore suggest using a subshell instead and putting that subshell in the background:

```
( strace -o mystrace.out -esetsid setsid sleep 123 ) &
```

Note, the subshell is not a separate process and you get directly the expected behaviour:

```
$ ( strace -o mystrace.out -esetsid setsid sleep 123 ) &
[1] 21077
$ ps f
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
20524 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
21077 pts/0    S      0:00  \_ strace -o mystrace.out -esetsid setsid sleep 123
21104 pts/0    R+     0:00  \_ ps f
```